# Add new col-12 after four portfolio items with php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a portfolio page where 4 items are next to eachother. Each item I wrapped in a col-3. What happens is, when I want to give a col-3 a margin, the item below the col-3 breaks and moves down.

I think it has something to do with all the portfolio items in one col-12, so after 4 items I would like to have the next 4 items in a new col-12, where I can give the portolio items each a col-3 again. That way I can play with the margins.

[image]

I use advanced custom fields to get the data.

```
<div class="container marketing mt130">
    <div class="col-md-12 central">
        <h1 class="mb20">Mentors</h1>       
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">         
            <?php 
                $mentors = get_field('mentors'); 
                    if($mentors):
                        foreach($mentors as $mentor =>$item):                               
                                        $mentor_image = $item['image_mentor'];                              
                                        $mentor_name = $item['name_mentor'];                                
                                        $mentor_location = $item['location_mentor'];                                
                                        $mentor_text = $item['text_mentor'];                            
                                        $mentor_twitter = $item['twitter_mentor'];  
                                        $mentor_fb = $item['facebook_mentor'];                              
            ?>      
        <div class="col-md-3 central">
            <div class="wrapper_mentor">
                <img src="<?php print $mentor_image ;?>" alt="<?php print $mentor_name ;?>" width="226" height="226">
                <div class="wrapper_mentor_text">
                    <h2 ><?php print $mentor_name ;?></h2>
                    <h3><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span><?php print $mentor_location ;?></h3>  
                        <div class="popup_mentor" style="display:none;">
                            <p><?php print $text ;?></p>                                
                            <p style="padding-left:20px; text-align:left;">
                                <a href="https://<?php print $member_twitter ;?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                <a href="https://<?php print $member_fb ;?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                  
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>                         
</div><!-- end col-md-12 -->
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add an image to your question to understand what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ofcourse. [link](http://i62.tinypic.com/2h4yjys.png)
At the moment i have 2 rows of 4 items each. Only if i want to give the name and location a padding, the layout breaks. If each 4 items have an own col, then it wouldn't break right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're nesting Bootstrap's grid use a structure like `.col-sm-12 > .row > .col-sm-4` instead of `.col-sm-12 > .col-sm-4`. The row is needed to offset the padding on the columns.

Next to that don't play with the margins/padding of the `.container`, `.row` & `.col-...` classes. This is the reason why your layout breaks down. If you want some additional margin add it to a `<div>` inside the `.col-...` columns.

Perhaps look at customizing the Bootstrap grid. Easiest way would be to look at the `@grid-gutter-width` http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Thank you for your information. If i add .row to my code now, every col-3 will get a row, but i just want every 4 portfolio items to get a.row or col-12, so that each 4 items have their own row. Then the layout will not break right?

Comment: If you create a `.row` with 4 `col-md-3` in it it will work. See http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/emzQdW. Do you perhaps have margin/padding styling on your `.central` class. If you add the output html and css instead of the php it might become easier to debug. Keep in mind that creating a row per four items might become an issue if you decide that on a smaller screen three items should be shown per row. In that case use a single row with every column inside it.

Comment: I understand that i need a row for the 4 items. The problem i have now is, that i want to add it dynamically. I use a foreach loop, so i have to have an if statement in the foreach saying that after every 4th portfolio item i need to make a new row. Only i can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: I added a row in each col-3 now. It seems to be working so thanks for that tip ckuijjer. Is it also a good habit to do it like that?

Comment: No you only need a `.row` inside a column if you want to nest the grid (adding columns inside columns). See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting